# using islice to read a text file chunk-by-chunk

Tags: python, coding-style, slice

i have a text file with several million of point (*x*,*y*,*z* etc). I am trying to read the first million of lines with ***islice*** in order to initialize a dictionary

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import islice

def point_grid_id(x, y, minx, maxy, size):
    """give id (row,col)"""
    col = int((x - minx) / size)
    row = int((maxy - y) / size)
    return row, col

def initialize_dict(filename, minx, maxy, size, chunk=1000000):
    point_dict = defaultdict(list)
    with open(filename, 'r') as datafile:
        for line in islice(datafile, chunk):
            point = line.rstrip().split(parse)
            point_dict[point_grid_id(float(point[0]), float(point[1]), minx, maxy, size)].append(point)
    return point_dict
```

where **minx**, **maxy** are the origin of a grid (left-up corner) and **size** the size of the grid. The `float(point[0])`, `float(point[1])` are the *x* and *y* of point-i

The **ID** is the location where the point-i drop.

```
point_dict = initialize_dict(filename, minx, maxy, 2)
```

using this dictionary i am trying to read the rest of points (~ 8 millions) and store in the dictionary the points with the **ID** already present as **Keys**. In other words the point with the ID not present in the dictionary are stored in a new text file, otherwise 
they are stored in the dictionary.

I am trying how to figure out a style to slice every 1 millions of point until the end of the file (unknown)

```
size = 2
with open(filename, 'r') as datafile:
    for line in islice(datafile, 1000000, 2000000):
        point = line.rstrip().split(parse)
        if point_grid_id(float(point[0]), float(point[1]), minx, maxy, size) in point_dict:
            point_dict[point_grid_id(float(point[0]), float(point[1]), minx, maxy, size)].append(point)
        else:
            pass
```

using this form i get always the fist 10 points

```
with open(filename, 'r') as datafile:
    for line in islice(datafile, 10):
        point = line.rstrip().split(";")
        print point
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just keep taking `islice(datafile, 1000000)` each islice will continue where the previous one left off. The problem is detecting the end of the file, you'll just keep getting empty islices.

A better pattern is to use `groupby`

```
from itertools import groupby, count
with open(filename, 'r') as datafile:
    groups = groupby(datafile, key=lambda k, line=count(): next(line)//1000000)
    for k, group in groups:
        for line in group:
            ...
```

The key for the grouping is the line number//1000000 so each group of 1000000 lines has the same key

Comment: hey @gnibbler, i tried to print (for each 10 by 10) but returning always the first 10

Comment: @Gianni, are you reopening the file between islices? You shouldn't do that

Comment: if i run the code that i posted now i get only the first 10 points

Comment: could you explain please where is my error? i really don't understand

Comment: @Gianni, you'd need to put the islices in a `while` loop. The problem is then edetecting the end of the file. There is a better pattern for that. I'll add it to my answer

Comment: thanks John. I really appreciate if you suggest me a better solution.

Comment: @john, do i have problem in the end of the file?